# Where is the Kendo.Mvc file

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have downloaded the sample at http://kendouisaleshub.com/ and to build it I need the reference Kendo.Mvc. Where do I find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have downloaded the Kendo Wrappers for MVC from the Kendo site, then you should have it available in `program files/telerik/kendo ... bins/`